# How can I download multiple images from Firebase Storage on Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage, flutter-web

I am developing a Flutter Web application that, after clicking a download button, I need to download multiple images from Firebase Storage.

How can I don this on Flutter Web?

UPDATE:

After following Frank's suggestion on the comments, and other posts. I wrote the following function:

```
Future<void> downloadProductImages() async {
//TODO: modify on suppliers admin that images are saved with the correct name.
final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();

int count = 1;
for (final ref in product.imgsMap.keys.toList()) {
  print(ref);
  try {
    final childRef = storageRef.child(ref);
    const maxSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
    final Uint8List data = (await childRef.getData(maxSize))!;
    //check if file is jpeg

    late String ext;
    if (data[0] == 0xFF &&
        data[1] == 0xD8 &&
        data[data.length - 2] == 0xFF &&
        data[data.length - 1] == 0xD9) {
      ext = 'jpeg';
    } else {
      ext = 'png';
    }

    // Data for "images/island.jpg" is returned, use this as needed.
    final content = base64Encode(data!.toList());
    AnchorElement(
        href:
            "data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-16le;base64,$content")
      //href: "image/$ext;charset=utf-16le;base64,$content")
      ..setAttribute("download", "${product.name}_$count.$ext")
      ..click();

    count++;
  } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
    //TODO: HANDLE EXCEPTIONS
    print(e);
  } on Exception catch (e) {
    // Handle any errors.
    print(e);
  }
}

// File file = // generated somewhere
// final rawData = file.readAsBytesSync();
}
```

On chrome mobile, the files are downloaded but are not recognized as pictures. It seems that the *AnchorElment* doesn't have the correct href.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage/#download-urls?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen page not found.

Comment: Oh yeah, wow... it looks like they literally just split the documentation up into separate page. It's now here: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/download-files

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I followed the documentation, however path_provider doesn't support web. I managed to follow instructions on other post using  dart:html. I can download the file, but it is not recognized as an image by chrome mobile.

Comment: That makes this quite a different question, so I recommend updating the title to reflect the one concrete problem that you're now asking for help with.